# Where clause in GROUP BY clause containing ranges

Tags: sql-server

I want a mechanism where the the number of reported cases for the age ranges will be for a particular date. But the `WHERE` clause `BioData.[Date] =  '05/16/2016'` is giving an error.

Can someone please help me to fix it.
My query is as following:

```
SELECT  t.[Range] AS [Age Range], COUNT(*) AS [Number of Reported Cases] 
FROM    (
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN Age BETWEEN  0 AND  6 THEN ' 0-6 ' 
                    WHEN Age BETWEEN 07 AND 17 THEN '10-19'
                    WHEN Age BETWEEN 18 AND 60 THEN '20-29'
                    ELSE '60+'
                END AS [Range]
            FROM BioData
        ) t
WHERE   BioData.[Date] = '05/16/2016'
GROUP   BY t.[Range]
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please share your table schema

Comment: how a range `between 07 and 17` is label  `'10-19'` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reformating your query with a tool like http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

```
SELECT t.range  AS [Age Range], 
       Count(*) AS [Number of Reported Cases] 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN ' 0-6 ' 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 07 AND 17 THEN '10-19' 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 60 THEN '20-29' 
                 ELSE '60+' 
               END AS range 
        FROM   biodata) t 
WHERE  biodata.[Date] = '05/16/2016' 
GROUP  BY t.range
```

You realize `[biodata]` doesnt exist because your `FROM` is just `[t]`

You probably are missing the `JOIN biodata` but because your question isnt clear I cant guess what else you need.

EDIT: After some digging I think you want this

```
SELECT t.range  AS [Age Range], 
       Count(*) AS [Number of Reported Cases] 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN ' 0-6 ' 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 07 AND 17 THEN '10-19' 
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 60 THEN '20-29' 
                 ELSE '60+' 
               END AS range 
        FROM   biodata
        WHERE  biodata.[Date] = '05/16/2016' ) t 
  --    ^^^ move where inside `t`
GROUP  BY t.range
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.